Is there a way to fix LineStrings cutting off on .kml files in Google Earth Pro?
I'm using the python library simplekml to make a .kml file that shows routes connecting airports with Points to show the airports and LineStrings to show possible flights. The generated .kml file shows up fine in the Google Earth website but on Google Earth Pro it cuts off depending on the zoom applied.
I have tried messing with the LineString attributes to see if I'm missing anything but nothing has worked so far. My code is the following:
        for i in range(len(path)):
            airport_coords = (
                airports_df[airports_df['Code'] == path[i]]['Longitude'].values[0],
                airports_df[airports_df['Code'] == path[i]]['Latitude'].values[0]
                )
            point = kml.newpoint(name=path[i], coords=[airport_coords])
            point.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/1417-trans-airport.png'
            point.style.iconstyle.scale = 3
            if i > 0:
                last_coords = (
                    airports_df[airports_df['Code'] == path[i-1]]['Longitude'].values[0],
                    airports_df[airports_df['Code'] == path[i-1]]['Latitude'].values[0]
                    )
                line = kml.newlinestring(name='Line', coords=[last_coords, airport_coords])
                line.style.linestyle.width = 3
                line.style.linestyle.altitudemode = simplekml.AltitudeMode.clamptoground
                line.style.linestyle.tessellate = 1
                line.style.linestyle.color = simplekml.Color.red

As you can see, I increased the line width, set the altitude mode clamped to the ground, and set tessellate to 1.
Below is an example image of the line cutting off:



The second image is in regular Google Earth, showing the line not cutting off. The red Xs are the icon for the airport not showing up properly in the browser version, but that is not really the issue.
Also, I am using the subprocess library to open the file in my desktop using Google Earth Pro. If there is a way to instead just load the file into the Google Earth website, that works as well.

As it turned out, tessellate and altitudemode aren't part of the styling of the line. Instead of:
line.style.linestyle.altitudemode = simplekml.AltitudeMode.clamptoground
line.style.linestyle.tessellate = 1

It should have been:
line.altitudemode = simplekml.AltitudeMode.clamptoground
line.tessellate = 1

